# How to install Panasonic KX-FLB883 network printer on Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, printing, network-printer

I have a Panasonic KX-FLB883 similar to [this one](http://www2.panasonic.com/consumer-electronics/shop/Phones-Fax/Fax-Printers/Multifunction-Printers/model.KX-FLB881_11002_7000000000000005702) on the Panasonic website and I am trying to install it on Ubuntu.

The computer detects it but it asks me for a driver or PPD file and I can't seem to find any of them.

Have anybody managed to install a similar printer on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like printers from that family have [not been included](http://www.openprinting.org/show_printer.cgi?recnum=Panasonic-KX-FLB801) in the foomatic DB yet. BTW: your precise model is neither in the list of known devices, so you might wish to contribute by [adding it](http://www.openprinting.org/edit_printer.cgi?make=Panasonic&model=KX-FLB801&newentry=1) yourself.

I did not do too much digging for your problem, but chances are in the meanwhile you could achieve partial (sometimes almost complete) functionality by forcing the use of a driver for a similar printer. See for example [this list](http://www.linuxprinting.org/printer_list.cgi?make=Panasonic).

HTH!

Comment: tnx. added the printer to the database. 
I tried to add generic drivers, but it only made the printer print out gibarish

Comment: @solomongaby Did you ever manage to resolve your issue? If you did, please consider either accepting an existing answer, or posting your own self-answer and accepting that.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work in OpenSUSE 13.2 x64, cups 1.5.4

I just use a ljet2p.ppd (Panasonic KX-P4410 Foomatic/ljet2p), wich is included in OpenPrinting rpm.

CUPS printer test page:

[image: CUPS printer test page]

Comment: Welcome to superuser, the question was about Ubuntu and with a Panasonic KX-FLB883 . If you could add where you found the "ljet2p.ppd" and a bit more detail it could be a more useful answer.